# Finding the DATEDIFF between two columns and creating its own column

Tags: mysql, datediff

Trying to find the DATEDIFF between two dates and display it as it's own column.
Here are my current columns:
[currentcolumns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTXFU.png)

And here is what I need:
[needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAJ1O.png)

Here is the code I have been running with error:

```
SELECT orderNumber, DATEDIFF(day,orderDate,shippedDate) AS day FROM datenumtest;
```

The error I get says: #1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF'

I've looked at a ton of sites now and can't seem to see what the issue is. Ideas?

Comment: `DATEDIFF` only has two parameters. `day` is not required as it always returns a value in days. See the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL's [`DATEDIFF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) function just takes two parameters:

```
SELECT orderNumber, DATEDIFF(shippedDate, orderDate) AS day
FROM datenumtest;
```

Note the order of the date parameters used, which would return some positive number of days assuming that the shipping date be greater than the order date.

Comment: Yes.  I saw your comment after I posted.

Comment: Thanks, you guys! Is there another one that requires 'day' in there? I swear I saw that everywhere I looked!

Comment: @ColleenMorrison MySQL's `DATEDIFF` returns days as the unit of the difference.  If you want some _other_ unit, then tell us what that is.

Comment: Nope, day is what I needed! I think I was just confused by the other resources I was seeing online. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

DATEDIFF function in MySQL only supports two input parameters, whereas SQL Server variant of the function supports to derive days, month etc by passing in the additional parameter.